# nodejs empty result gives error

Tags: node.js

Something weird is happening here. This is my code :

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    connection.query('SELECT message FROM messages', function(err, docs, fields) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        console.log(fields);
        if(docs[0].message!='') {
            res.render('page', {messages: docs});
        }
        else {
            res.render('page');
        }
    });
});
```

if there are any rows in the "messages" table, it's working fine, but if its empty, its returning this error at the "if (err) {" line :

```
Error: Must have start <= end
    at Buffer.toString (buffer.js:416:26)
```

Any idea what is happening here?

Comment: what is `connection`?  Are you using a particular package?

Comment: yes "connection" is the connection object of "mysql" package